# Creating variables inside for loop when size of list is unknown

Tags: java, android, list, http, for-loop

I apologize in advance if this question is stupid but I'm working on something at the moment which required me to implement a loop to parse through a `List` of objects of type `MenuItem`. Inside the loop I need to store the name of the object in a `String` variable.

However I am unsure about how many items will be in the `List` and therefor do not know how many `variables` I require. Can I somehow declare variables on the fly inside of the loop???
Below is my current code:

```
for(int i = 0; i != orderItems.size(); i++){
                MenuItem item = orderItems.get(i);
                String itemName = item.getName();
            }
```

The reason for the loop above is because when it exits I want to send all of the `itemName` variables to a db via a `Http` post request. So I can pass as a parameter like this:

```
    new RequestTask().execute(url, itemName1, itemName2, itemName3);
```

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Not relevant to your question but I think you should change `i != orderItems.size()` to `i < orderItems.size()`

Comment: Presumably orderItems is some sort of aggregate -- Java has a bunch of those -- Stack, Vector, ArrayList, etc.  Use one of them.

Answer (score 2):

You can use varargs to specify a method that accepts a list of variables. In the end it is just a method that accepts an array of such variables. So you will end with

```
  new RequestTask().execute(url, items);  // items is String[]
```

If you do not know `a priori` the number of Strings, store them in a List. You then can get the number of items in the list, create an array big enough and fill it. Or, use the method `toArray` that will do just that.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the ArrayList syntax I use all the time when looping on an unknown value. I then convert it to a normal array for further processing.

```
List<String> itemNameList = new ArrayList<String>();
for(int i = 0; i != orderItems.size(); i++) {
    MenuItem item = orderItems.get(i);
    itemNameList.add(item.getName());
}
String[] itemNameArray = new String[itemNameList.size()];
itemNameList.toArray(itemNameArray);
```

Answer (score 0):

Put them into a list of some sort ie;

```
    ArrayList<String> itemNameList = new ArrayList<String>();
    for(int i = 0; i != orderItems.size(); i++){ 
         MenuItem item = orderItems.get(i);
         String itemName = item.getName();
         itemNameList.add(itemName);
    }
```